# Replace all black-labeled items if not part of the white-labeled items in text

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to replace all occurrences from text with *, which are

- available in the black-labeled list and
- bordered by (spaces or "," or "." or start or end of text) and
- not part of any white-labeled item

Example:

```
["is", "panter"] // black-labeled
["pink panter", "blue panter"] // white-labeled


"This is pink panter." -> "This * pink panter."
"This is black panter." -> "This * black *."

String input = ...; 
List<String> whiteLabelded = ...; 
List<String> blackLabelded = ...; 
String enhencedText  = enhenceText(input, whiteLabelded, blackLabelded);
```

My try:

```
Map<String, String> whiteLabeldedMap = assignUniquePlaceHolder(whiteLabelded); // like ####1, ####2, ####3
String output = input;
whiteLabeldedMap.forEach((key, value) -> output = output.replace(key, value)); // replace white labeled strings
blackLabelded.forEach(key -> output = output.replace(key, "*")); // replace black labeled strings
whiteLabeldedMap.forEach((key, value) -> output = output.replace(value, key)); // return white labeled strings
```

Is it possible to implement better?

Comment: What have you tried? One approach I can think of would be to find where you have white labeled substring (start and end) and ignore these substrings when looking for black labeledt string. So in your first example you find pink panter so you only look for black labelled words in "This is " and "."

Comment: I agree, in logic it's trivial, but in code is not so.

Comment: Do you want to replace the text whereever it is, or just along word boundaries? Because in the first case, This should be replaced by Th*...

Comment: I need to replace only content bordered by spaces. 'is' from This will not be replaced. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first version that roughly does what you want, very inefficiently, but hey, it needs to be correct before it's fast. Adapt to your needs and improve performance if needed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BlackWhiteLists {

    /**
     * Replace words in black lists by * unless they are in whitelist
     * @param input the input
     * @param white the white list
     * @param black the black list
     * @return the replaced string
     */
    public static String enhanceText(String input, List<String> white, List<String> black) {
        String result=input;
        for (String bs:black) {
            // find text to remove
            int ix=result.indexOf(bs);
            
            while (ix>-1) {
                boolean ok=true;
                // find if text we want to keep overlaps
                for (String ws:white) {
                    int ix2=input.indexOf(ws);
                    while (ok && ix2>-1) {
                        // overlaps
                        if (ix>=ix2 && ix<ix2+ws.length() ) {
                            ok=false;
                        }
                        // search for next instance of white
                        ix2=input.indexOf(ws,ix2+ws.length());
                    }
                }
                // no overlap, we replace
                if (ok && isWord(result,ix,bs.length())) {
                    result=result.substring(0,ix)+"*"+result.substring(ix+bs.length());
                    // search for next instance of black
                    ix=result.indexOf(bs,ix+1);
                } else {
                    // search for next instance of black
                    ix=result.indexOf(bs,ix+bs.length());
                }
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * Is the text at the specific place in the input a word
     * @param input the input string
     * @param ix the start index
     * @param length the text length
     * @return true if the text is not preceded or followed by another letter
     */
    public static boolean isWord(String input, int ix, int length) {
        if (ix>0) {
            if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(ix-1))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (ix+length<input.length()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(ix+length))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> white=Arrays.asList("pink panter", "blue panter");
        List<String> black=Arrays.asList("is", "panter");
        System.out.println(enhanceText("This is pink panter.",white,black));
        System.out.println(enhanceText("This is black panter.",white,black));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why -1 on the question? What is wrong?

Comment: Because you're asking people to write code for you, without providing any attempt yourself. This is not a site where people do your homework for you, but where we help people that also help themselves. So even providing a broken incomplete implementation would get you more goodwill.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer and explanation. I updated the question with my pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is of help. Anyway i assume you want to solve this task with some hints? So here are some hints:

A text can be considered an array of characters (assuming it is one long string). First letter has index 0 and the last character has index "length-1".

```
                    1                   2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
T h i s   i s   b l a c k   p a n t e r .
```

Knowing this you can start the comparisons:

1. for a black labeled string (here: panter) see if it is found in the string
2. if the string is not found -> good. nothing to do
   if the string is found write down the index where it starts (java string substring gives information about this) and how long it is (eg start index 14, length 6 for given example "panter")
3. now do for all white labeled items
   find if it matches the string and if it does: find where the start index is and how long the match is (eg match at position 8 and length is 12 for above example black panter)
   (java string object has methods for this) if the location overlaps with the location from step 2. than the string is white labeled and will remain unchanged. Otherwise it has to be replaced (again the java string object has methods for his)